# How to get type of key and value of a Map type definition in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given a type of Map, for example:

```
type Foo = Map<string, number>;
```

Is there a way to then get the type that was used for the `key` and for the `value`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like this to extract the key and value of any map you want:

```
type Foo = Map<string, number>;

type MapKey<T> = T extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
type MapValue<T> = T extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never;

type FooKey = MapKey<Foo>
type FooValue = MapValue<Foo>

// Or if you just need it for the current case:

type FooKey2 = Foo extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
type FooValue2 = Foo extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never;
```

Comment: Amazing! I like it!

Answer (score 2):

A (horrible) way it could be

```js
type Foo = Map<string, number>;

type Key = Parameters<Foo["set"]>[0];
type Value = Parameters<Foo["set"]>[1];
```

Comment: I think this was actually how it was done before `infer` was introduced.

Comment: maybe, the solution by Garuno is much better than mine

Comment: Yeah, I prefer the other solution as well, but thanks for giving an alternative too :)